# AppImage : When deployed in another system , does it use the .so files which is bundled in it ..or the ones present in distributed system?

Tags: c++, opencv, shared-libraries, openvino, appimage

I am creating a .appimage in my system for an application which uses libraries from openvino..When deploying that on another system..it gives me symbol lookup error in opencv Mat() function..

The distributed system has openvino installed but it is a older version than what I used..So when running..the AppImage or AppRun from AppDir folder uses the opencv libraries from the system(which is older one)

Do..AppImage always prefer system libraries first..and comes to bundled libraries if they are not present in system

Error is

```
./Check-Video-x86_64.AppImage 
./Check-Video-x86_64.AppImage: symbol lookup error: ./Check-Video-x86_64.AppImage: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3MatC1Ev
```

Any insights about appImage library preferences and solving the error?

Comment: Could you please share which tool are you using to create your AppImage.

Comment: linuxdeployqt is the tool I am using ...    ```./linuxdeployqt-continuous-x86_64.AppImage path/to/executable -qmldir='path/to/qml/dir' -verbose=2 -appimage```  ...Using this command in prompt

Comment: linuxdeployqt is a bit outdated and is keep in life support only to not break the CI of the people that are already using it. There are other more modern tools that can help you in the task, please consider using appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/ or https://github.com/linuxdeploy

Comment: Thank u..I will try with that

Answer (score 1):

It uses both, with preference on the bundled ones. So if a given `.so` is bundled it will be used. Usually low level libraries such as glibc and drivers are not included. This is a gamble looking for a better portability and reducing the bundle size. Notice that depending on the method (or tool) used to create the AppImage this may vary.

You can use the debug feature of the system linker to know which files are being really loaded as follows:

`LD_DEBUG=libs ./yourapp.AppImage`